# Android Activity ASyncTask and onCancelled

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an activity that adds any AsyncTask it starts to a vector-list.

When the activity is destroyed it goes through the vector-list and calls onCancelled on all AsyncTasks.

OnCancelled is thus called in each AsyncTask which sets some private fields to null. These private fields referenced some objects owned by the activity. This together with AsyncTasks checking for "isCancelled" this means the AsyncTasks will stop in a clean way.

Each AsyncTask also has a reference to the vector-list.

This leaves some remaining issues / questions:

- Since AsyncTask has bitten me in the past: For the below questions, is the behavior **consistent** across API >= 8?
- I assume *onCancelled* is only called if *cancel* is called. That means that in such cases is it reasonable to let the activity maintain the vector-list and simply null the reference to it in the AsyncTask?
- In an AsyncTask descendant, in what thread is onCancelled running? The AsyncTask one or the main-ui-activity one calling "Cancel"? (this is important for thread safety of nulling private fields)
- Should each AsyncTask find and remove itself from the list when done and destroyed? Assuming the destructor runs in the AsyncTask thread, do I just need to synchronize the find/delete operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)The only inconsistency I know of in AsyncTask is execute being truly parallel vs it being round robin on a single thread and executeOnExecutor being truly parallel.

2)Yes, onCancelled is only called if cancel is called.  However note the docs:  Runs on the UI thread after cancel(boolean) is invoked and doInBackground(Object[]) has finished.

This means onCancelled will not be called immediately on any thread.

3)UI thread, as per docs

4)Java doesn't have destructors.  It has finalizers, which may never be called, or may be called 4 days from now.  You cannot rely on them.

Comment: Thanks! I have gotten closer to a design where I can "prove" no threading problem can occur. I am not there yet, but will be. (Will creatt a separate SO for that if I have more questions.)